# Getting an error message while running an appium

Tags: appium-ios

In eclipse console getting the below error message.

A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 91.11 seconds

Given proper App path,Bundle ID everything. 
App is launching and crashing again and again.

So kindly provide the suggestion to get over it.

Answer (score 0):

first,delete all simulator and  create new simulator from xcode >window> devices(+ to create new simulator)

Than, click xcode> open developer tool> instruments (open it) than

click on ui automation. after opening  ui automation window, select ur device from the top and wait until the simulator is fully open.